# private variables being modified outside of class - Java

Tags: java, private-members

I'm looping through some data, creating an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>>` of each step. Each `Cell` class stores a `row` and `col` (among other things).

My problem is that when I investigate my `listOfCells` afterward, every `Cell` object has the same row (the last row of `myData`. This only happens with `row`, the columns are as they should be (that is, unique to themselves). From what I can tell, `row` is incrementing properly, but when it does, it changes all the values of `row` in my `listOfCells`.

I have no idea what's causing this.

## Creating `Cell`'s

```
Cell cell = null;
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
ArrayList<Cell> tmpCellList = new ArrayList<Cell>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> listOfCells = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>>();    

for (ArrayList<double> eachRow : myData) {
    row++;
    for (double eachCol : eachRow) {
        col++;
        cell = new Cell();
        cell.setCol(col);
        cell.setRow(row);
        cell.setValue(eachCol);
        tmpCellList.add(cell);
    }
    listOfCells.add(row-1, tmpCellList);
 }
```

## `Cell` Class

```
public class Cell {
    private int row;
    private int col;
    private double value;
    
public void setRow(int rowIn)   {
    this.row = rowIn;
}
    
public int getRow() {
    return row;
}

public void setCol(int colIn)   {
    this.col = colIn;
}

public int getCol() {
    return col;
}

    public void setValue(double val) {
            this.value = val;
    }

    public double getValue() {
            return value;
    }
```

Comment: Move your `ArrayList<Cell> tmpCellList = new ArrayList<Cell>();` inside the first for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of your rows are the same `ArrayList<Cell>`.
Therefore, they all contain the same cells.

You need to create a `new ArrayList<Cell>()` for each row.